# Applying Domain Name to EC2 Instance

Tags: nginx, dns, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I want to host a new subdomain on an Ec2 Instance(`ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`) like `blog.somesite.com`

I have the DNS settings on a 3rd party host(like Godaddy) that look like:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

`site ip addr` as shown above, is the value of the ec2 server e.g. `xxx.xxx.xx.xx` and not

```
ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

If I try to do an **mxtoolbox** lookup on `DNS` for `blog.myapp.com`, it seems to have properly propogated the A-Record, do I need a `CNAME` record instead of A-Record?

If I try to access `blog.myapp.com` via browser, it is just a never ending connection. If I access `myapp.com` , it has always been working fine.

On my ec2 box, I'm running nginx, does something need to be configured on nginx too?

Sorry about the newbieness - still learning.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to "ping blog.myapp.com" from a terminal (dunno what os you are on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you should assign an elastic IP to your instance. IP addresses will change if the instance is ever stopped. With an elastic IP, you can re-associate the ip address to the instance if you need to stop it.

If you are setting up a DNS record for the apex, it needs to be an A record (Apex records is your domain with no subdomain).

For the domain `blog.yourdomain.com` you can set up either an A or CNAME record.

You will likely need to configure your host within nginx to respond to requests with your domain name.

You will also need to make sure port 80 is open on your security group, and system firewall if your OS has one configured.

Comment: Do I need a new elastic ip for different subdomains? e.g. the somedomain.com is on (1) elastic ip right now, and I have the blog.somedomain.com pointing to the same elastic ip that the somedomain.com is running on. Do I need a new one, for each individual subdomain?

Comment: Same is perfectly fine. Although you will likely want to configure nginx to redirect other sudomains to what you consider your default domain. Having the same content show up on multiple domains is bad for SEO.

Comment: Is an A-record pointing to the same IP address (elastic EC2 addr) fine? Do I just need to configure nginx to show different content for blog.somedomain.com and not the same content as somedomain.com ?

Comment: Both records can point to the same IP. Assuming blog.yourdomain.com is your default domain, you should redirect requests to yourdomain.com to blog.yourdomain.com

Comment: The primary domain is yourdomain.com, blog.somedomain.com is a sub-site of yourdomain.com

Comment: If they are two different sites, then skip the redirect. You can point to domains at the same instance. Nginx will differentiate between the sites. Need separate `server` configs for both.

Comment: Same root Tld - yourdomain, but one site is the home (e.g. yourdomain.com) and the other is a blog (e.g. blog.yourdomain.com) - perhaps I need to just modify nginx config to include (blog.yourdomain.com) , right ?

Comment: Any example or resources are welcome and helpful pertaining to this. Thanks @datasage

Comment: This is an example of a config with multiple sites: http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample I do think ubuntu has a sites-enabled folder in which you can put individual server configurations. You will just need to set up a `server {}` clause for each site with unique `server_name` directives

Comment: Great point here datasage - I really appreciate the help. Thanks :)